# Positioning strings to x-axis with same spacing

Tags: python, matplotlib

In Python, I have two lists that each contain some elements

```
Chemical_elements= [11,12,20,21.1,22,23,24,25,26]        
Other_values=[0.1,0.2,-0.03,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2]
```

Now I want to plot a simple figure as `x=Chemical_elements` and `y=other_values`.

The problem I'm facing is to assign the x-axis tickets into strings namely:

```
xticks=['Na','Mg', 'Ca', 'Sc', 'Ti', 'v' ,'Cr','Mn','Fe']
```

I tried the following:

```
locs, labels = xticks()

xticks(np.arange(10, 70, step=5))

xticks(np.arange(10), ('Na','Mg', 'Ca', 'Sc', 'Ti', 'v' ,'Cr','Mn','Fe'))
```

[image: The attached figure shows what I want]

Comment: Why didn't it work?

Comment: I don't understand the rationale here. Your data points are not evenly spaced (11, 12, 20...), but your labels ('Na','Mg', 'Ca',...) should be? How would you know with this strategy which label belongs to which point?

Comment: you make sense and that's my problem
let's say that the first point is (12.0, 0.2) and  another point is (24.0, 0.2)
Now I want to plot those to points, with it's real value but instead of using 12.0 in x-axis I want to have Mg and Cr for 24.0.
please look at the attached figure to have a better understanding.

Comment: these x-axis values are not meaningful, but I need to locate those strings in the right positions, I was able to do that but since each string is assigned to a different non-homogeneous value, so I got some strings crowded in middle (around 22) and scattered for the starting points or the ending ones.

Comment: Still not sure what the desired output is. Most probably you want to use  `ax.set_xticks(Chemical_elements)` with `ax.set_xticklabels(xticks)`. Or maybe simply `plt.plot(Chemical_elements, Other_values)` in matplotlib > 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works fine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Chemical_elements= [11,12,20,21.1,22,23,24,25,26]
Other_values = [0.1,0.2,-0.03,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2]

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize = (10, 5))
ax.plot(Chemical_elements, Other_values)

xticks_location = np.linspace(min(Chemical_elements), max(Chemical_elements), len(Chemical_elements))
xticks_labels = ['Na','Mg', 'Ca', 'Sc', 'Ti', 'v' ,'Cr','Mn','Fe']

ax.set_xticks(xticks_location)
ax.set_xticklabels(xticks_labels)

plt.show()
```